# Split 7 digit into separate columns in csv with python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, digits

Hi I have 100 data in csv file
I want to split 7 digit number into seprate columns with python
My csv file is like this:

| A |
| --- |
| 1234567 |

Split into new columns:

| B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

I try

```
Splitdigit=  df['A']>str.split(expand=true).add_perfix('A')
```

Comment: Do you always have 7 digits? If not what should be the output?

Comment: Yes always my output must be like the table above but it dosent worked I dont now where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have strings, you can use:

```
out = df['A'].astype(str).str.split('(?<=.)(?=.)', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

With the column names:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

out = (df['A'].astype(str).str.split('(?<=.)(?=.)', expand=True)
              .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase[1:])))
      )
```

Output:

```
   B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```